# List values from postgreSQL database PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

How can I list the values and display them like columns?The idea is have something like this:

```
NAME1 -TAB- NAME4 -TAB- NAME7
NAME2 -TAB- NAME5 -TAB- NAME8
NAME3 -TAB- NAME6 -TAB- NAME9
```

Instead of listing

```
NAME1 NAME2 NAME3 NAME4 NAME5 NAME6 NAME7 NAME8 NAME9
```

Comment: A little formatting here would go a long way.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the list is an PHP array

```
<?php
$list = array(...);
$items_per_column = floor(count($list)/3); //3 because 3 columns
for($i = 0 ; $i < $items_per_column ; $i++) {
    echo $list[$i] . "\t" . $list[$i+$items_per_column] . "\t" . $list[$i+$items_per_column*2] 
}
```

You need to find out how many items goes into a column. Let's say their are 9 items divide over 3 columns is 3 items per column. The for loop speaks for itself I think.